# Is there an online site or API that provides definitive, uncensored translations of internet slang words?

Tags: meaning, slang, translation, linguistics, social-media

I am a computer scientist studying on sentiment analysis. I need to retrieve **uncensored translations** of internet slang words such as `wtf`, `lmfao`. There are some websites that provide translations for slang words but they censor some letters if the translation contains *"nasty"* words.

Your recommendations are highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** Since I am developing a software, there will be no human-aid during translations. So what I exactly need is a service that provides first (most well-known) meanings of slang words.

Comment: Re your edit:  Good luck with that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily use [this list on Wiktionary.org](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_internet_slang). It requires attribution according to [these terms](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).

Answer (score 4):

If you haven't found www.urbandictionary.com yet, that site has very much useful information and it is certainly uncensored. Be aware though that the explanations with the highest ranks are not necessarily the most "correct" ones, people tend to vote for funny/smart definitions.

Comment: Actually I am aware of urbandictionary.com; but it provides multiple translations. Since I am developing a software, there will be no human-aid during translations. What I exactly need is a service that provides exact (first, most well-known) meanings of slang words.

Comment: @talha06 - But many slang terms have mulitple diverse definitions, highly dependent on context and local vernacular.

Comment: As I highlighted the most well-known one will be enough for me; just like NoSlang.com does - the reason I am not able to use it is that it censors some letters of nasty words.

Answer (score 0):

I just googled What is wtf in Internet slang and found internetslang.com,
which has an answer as to wtf (What the fuck...?).

http://www.internetslang.com/WTF-meaning-definition.asp

Comment: [http://internetslang.com](http://internetslang.com) provides censored translations.